# Git rebase: fixup by running command

Tags: git, rebase, git-amend

I'm on a branch that's many commits (in a straight line of history) ahead of my `develop` branch, and in each commit message is the name of the issue-tracker ticket I'm working on.  Now I want to rebase through each commit and change the name of that ticket to a different ticket, conceptually something like:

```
perl -pi -e 's/BB-123/BB-456/' .git/COMMIT_EDITMSG
```

Is there a way to tell rebase's `reword` action that instead of opening an interactive editor, I want to run a command on the message text instead?

The best I've come up with would be to put an `exec` action after each commit that runs `git commit --amend` and changes the `$EDITOR` variable to the above command or something, but that's pretty horrible.

Without a good automatic solution, I usually rebase with a `reword` action on every commit and edit all the messages manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably looking for `git filter-branch`.  Suppose your log looks like this:

```
* commit 7534b4609b84b87232ad933c83d5b802adfe2814 (HEAD -> wip/T1234)
|
|     More work on ticket #1234
|
* commit e23ef0941b7a52dbb46876db4c985a1c30ec5e16
|
|     Some work on ticket #1234
|
* commit b660a05e4d90fc8ae61b7d39e716ee3cdcc382ec (develop)
|
|     Current develop branch head
|
* commit 1b67c0b8b1b4f4c22ddc38ba78c499dde749006f

      Initial commit
```

So, you have a straight-line history of commits from `develop` to `wip/T1234`.  You realize the ticket should have read #1236, so you run:

```
$ git filter-branch --msg-filter 'sed -e s/1234/1236/g' \
>    develop..wip/T1234
Rewrite 7534b4609b84b87232ad933c83d5b802adfe2814 (2/2) (0 seconds passed,
remaining 0 predicted)
Ref 'refs/heads/wip/T1234' was rewritten
$
```

and now the commits are rewritten:

```
* commit c30e8becea1221d563d2be0e5a8c048c2c5bf608 (HEAD -> wip/T1234)
|
|     More work on ticket #1236
|
* commit 0417b49944b3c9311031a657bc8be3c8bf05b54d
|
|     Some work on ticket #1236
|
* commit b660a05e4d90fc8ae61b7d39e716ee3cdcc382ec (develop)
|
|     Current develop branch head
|
* commit 1b67c0b8b1b4f4c22ddc38ba78c499dde749006f

      Initial commit
```

A copy of the original refs will be written to `refs/original`, so you can still access the pre-filtered version:

```
$ git log refs/original/logs/refs/heads/wip/T1234
... version with #1234 still in place
```

Obviously, you want to check the rewrites carefully before removing the originals!

Comment: That worked great, thanks!  I've only ever used `filter-branch` to get rid of commits, or large files from the history, this is a nice skill to learn.

Answer (score 2):

Yes: when an interactive rebase opens the editor, it opens one based on different environment settings:

- `GIT_SEQUENCE_EDITOR` is used for the *commands to run*, but
- `GIT_EDITOR` is used for *reword* operations.

(If one of these is not set, Git falls back to `sequence.editor` or `core.editor` or the built in editor as usual.  You could change those settings, perhaps temporarily, but the environment variable is easier.)

Hence you can use:

```
GIT_SEQUENCE_EDITOR=script1 GIT_EDITOR=script2 git rebase -i <arguments>
```

where `script1` replaces `edit` with `reword`, and `script2` does the `s/BB-123/BB-456/` you want, for instance.

Comment: Thanks, that sounds like exactly what I want.  I can't quite get it to work, though: `% GIT_SEQUENCE_EDITOR='perl -pi -e "s/^keep/reword/m"' GIT_EDITOR='perl -pi -e "s/BB-123/BB-456/g"' git rebase -i develop` seems to just accept all commits without changing anything.

Comment: Hm. Might be interesting to run this with `GIT_TRACE=1` in front, so you can see it operate. In older Git, rebase is a shell script and every operation will be obvious. In newer Git it's been rewritten in C to use the sequencer so it may not be as obvious. It *should* work...

Comment: I tried it with a trace, here's a Gist of it: https://gist.github.com/kenahoo/99a16f2afcd274ebafad9e318a1ff90d .  Not sure what those two `git-sh-i18n--envsubst` lines are, are those supposed to be editor invocations?

Comment: Yikes. This thing is new to me, and [the documentation for it](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/git-sh-i18n--envsubst.txt) is a real shot across the bow. :-) "Don't use it" indeed... Anyway, it seems in this case it decided no commits needed picking (?!), so it did not generate a script. If it had there would be at least a few more "run-command" lines in there.

Comment: ```GIT_SEQUENCE_EDITOR='perl -pi -e "s/^keep/reword/m"'``` should be ```GIT_SEQUENCE_EDITOR='perl -pi -e "s/^pick/reword/m"'``` at least on git version 2.31.1.

Comment: @mj41: yes, it's always been "edit" as far as I know.